# Java Date Pattern in SimpleDateFormat doesn't work in SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

I am using the following statements to change the pattern of date to be stored in "MM/dd/yyyy" format. In my SQL database, Date field is in "DATE" type format. But, I can't understand why in my database still it shows the value as "2014-02-21". It seems very weird to me, because I have defined a pattern for date.

I appreciate any help, I spent a day on it...still stuck and can't proceed:(

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String s=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        java.util.Date myDate=new java.util.Date(s);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
        timeVO.set_Date(sqlDate); (store sqlDate in timeVO object- sqlDate is Date      type defined in object)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to convert a Date value to string to submit to database ... have you tried `timeVO.set_Date(cal.getTime());` or is it not possible because of the method signature?

Comment: (Wikipedia page for **ISO 8601**)
expressed according to ISO 8601:
Date: 2014-02-17

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how sql server handles dates, but I suppose that the format is not stored in database, dbms stores date objects as a number  (e.g. number of seconds since 01.01.1970), so does JVM, and date format is just a representation for printing it on screen - the thing you see in your database is only a printable form shown by your database client, and not how actually it is stored behind the scenes

Comment: +1 - Yes, most modern RDBMSs do essentially what the JVM does, and store an offset since a given epoch (this makes sorting/searching really efficient/simple).  This is _exactly_ what his problem is; resolution depends on what he's actually looking for...  probably, he needs to update the display format used in his client.  The `DATE` type itself can't be changed.  Attempting to store the value in the given format in a character-based type will result in a **lot** of trouble later.